# '£' character does not seem to encode properly - expect '%a3' but get '%u00a3'

Tags: c#, encoding, iso-8859-1

I want to send The pound sign character i.e. '£' encoded as ISO-8859-1 across the wire.
I perform this by doing the following:

```
var _encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
var _requestContent = _encoding.GetBytes(requestContent);
var _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);

_request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding] = _encoding.WebName;
_request.Method = "POST";
_request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1";
_request.ContentLength = _requestContent.Length;

_requestStream = _request.GetRequestStream();
_requestStream.Write(_requestContent, 0, _requestContent.Length);
_requestStream.Flush();
_requestStream.Close();
```

When I put a breakpoint at the target, I expect to receive the following:
'%a3', however I receive '%u00a3' instead. We have tested many odd characters, but '£' seems to be the only character where theres a problem.

Does anyone know what the problem is here? - Help would be greatly appreciated...

Billy

Comment: I'm not too sure how to help, but ouf of curiosity, can you not use utf8 for the encoding? Is usually a lot less error prone to such problems.

Comment: Cant use UTF8 as the server that we call out to (third party service) insist on using ISO 8859-1

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but would be interested to know what happens if you use Encoding.Default and 'windows-1252' as the encodings (see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/encoding.html).

Comment: Paul,

See my answer where I have made a little progress.
I have a new question now, you may be able to answer this.

Cheers for the help

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, they are equivalent. If the server chokes, well then the server probably does not support escaped Unicode.

Comment: The server is not choking, just the '£' symbol is not being encoded as expected. The server that receives the message still operates correctly.

Comment: @user243143: I fail to see the problem then  :)

Answer (score 0):

From a bit of research Ì found:

ISO-8859-1 is divided into 2 groups of characters: (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1)

The lower range 20 to 7E - where all characters seem to be encoded correctly
The higher range A0 to FF - where all characters seem to encode to their Unicode equivalent value

As '£' is in higher range A0 to FF, it gets encoded to %u00a3. In fact when I use the first few characters of the higher range A0 to FF i.e. '¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®', I get '%u00a1%u00a2%u00a3%u00a4%u00a5%u00a6%u00a7%u00a8%u00a9%u00aa%u00ab%u00ac%u00ae'. This behaviour is consistent.

The question I now have is why do characters in the higher range A0 to FF get encoded to their unicode value - and not to their equivalent ISO-8859-1 value?

%u00a1%u00a2%u00a3%u00a4%u00a5%u00a6%u00a7%u00a8%u00a9%u00aa%u00ab%u00ac+%u00ae